# Average price change over a period of time SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the average price change for several items. This is my first time using SQL server, coming from some light experience in Oracle SQL and MySQL. The table is set up like this:

| ProductID | StartDate | EndDate | StandardCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 707 | 5/31/11 | 5/29/12 | 12.2 |
| 707 | 5/30/12 | 5/29/13 | 13 |
| 707 | 5/30/13 | null | 13.5 |
| 708 | 5/31/11 | 5/29/12 | 10 |
| 708 | 5/30/12 | 5/29/13 | 11 |
| 708 | 5/30/13 | null | 12 |

I would like it to return this:

| ProductID | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 707 | 1.3 |
| 708 | 2 |

```
with a as
    (
        select 
            productID, standardcost, startDate, ISNULL(endDate, GETDATE())
        from
            production.ProductCostHistory 
        where (productID, endDate) in (select 
                              productID, max(endDate)
                          from 
                              Production.ProductCostHistory
                          group by
                              productID
                         )
    ), 
b as 
    (
        select 
            productID, standardcost, startDate, startDate
        from
            production.ProductCostHistory 
        where (productID, startDate) in (select 
                              productID, min(StartDate)
                          from 
                              Production.ProductCostHistory
                          group by
                              productID
                         )
    )

select 
    a.productID, (a.standardcost - b.standardcost) difference  
from
     a join b
    on a.ProductID = b.ProductID and 
       a.startDate = b.startDate and
       a.EndDate = b.EndDate
```

The idea is to first get the price with the most recent end date, then subtract the price from the oldest start date, to get the change in cost over that period of time. I understand that the `where ... in` does not work like in Oracle SQL, but I have not found a way to use `exists` the way that I need it to work. The averaging will be done in PowerBI, so I'm not worried about doing that in the Query. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You can directly get max, min using a group by and join with the result. BTW here is SO people tend to skip questions with pictures. Sample data as text is useful, but not as a picture. If you can supply sample data and desired output I think you would get a reply.

Comment: @DaleK sorry, updated both the table and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calculating the Standardcosts corresponding to the first startdate, and latest enddate (for each product) using an analytic function `FIRST_VALUE`.

```
select 
    productid,
    max(fv) as value_at_first_startdate,
    max(lv) as value_at_latest_enddate,
    diff = max(lv) - max(fv)
from (
    select 
        productid,
        first_value(standardcost)
            over (partition by productid
                order by startdate) as fv,
        first_value(standardcost)
            over (partition by productid
                order by case when enddate is null then 0 else 1 end
                , enddate desc) as lv
    from cte
) t
group by productid
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but would you mind explaining the second `partition by`? I'm a bit confused about how the case statement works there.

Comment: It is probably the second order by clause you are talking about. I think it is equivalent to saying that null's are preferred in the ordering, which implies that enddate for that standard cost tag has not yet been updated in the table (-> its the last record for a given productid). And the second enddate is just the safety measure for cases if temporal logic of a table changes to writing '2099-01-01' for example, instead of nulls for the enddate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SQL is supposed to return correct result:

```
with minmax (productId, minStart, maxEnd) as 
( select 
    productID, min(startDate),max(endDate)
  from 
    Production.ProductCostHistory
    group by productID
),
a as
    (
        select 
            p.productID, standardcost, startDate, ISNULL(endDate, GETDATE())
        from production.ProductCostHistory p
        inner join minmax m on m.productId = p.productId AND 
                        m.maxEnd = p.endDate
    ), 
b as 
    (
        select 
            p.productID, standardcost, startdate, startdate
        from production.ProductCostHistory p
        inner join minmax m on m.productId = p.productId AND 
                        m.minStart = p.startDate
    )

select 
    a.productID, (a.standardcost - b.standardcost) difference  
from
     a join b
    on a.ProductID = b.ProductID and 
       a.startDate = b.startDate and
       a.EndDate = b.EndDate
```

Comment: This seems to only return only the ones that do not change at all, ie only a single row in the table.

Comment: @vito, It is basically your code. As I said written based on yours, since you didn't give any sample data nor desired output you shouldn't expect it to be right if yours is not.